# Communication with Android over WiFi

Tags: networking, wifi, server, java, android

I'm aiming to connect to a Raspberry Pi from my Android phone over WiFi (WiFi direct isn't supported in my phone). I just need to forward character based commands to an Arduino board and maybe send a video stream back from Raspberry Pi to the phone as a further goal.

I did some searching online and found applications using the `URLConnection` to pass the IP and the port while the Raspberry Pi server is running, but are there any other ways? What is the best one for video streaming (my future goal)?

Comment: Has this been solved? If so, please mark the answer that fixed it as such. We're trying to get this site up to par and the Q:A ratio is really bad. Thanks! goldilocks answer seems to solve this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For video streaming, both the pi and Android can make use of [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA) via various client/server applications (on raspbian, see `rygel` or `minidlna`), although I'm not sure if those can be made to suit your purposes.

For just logging onto the pi, there are SSH clients for Android -- "Juice SSH" is good.